# Will I be able to upgrade my equipment from Mk I in NG+?

Tags: the-surge

To upgrade equipment in *The Surge*, you need to gather from the fallen enemies broken parts from a certain tier. For example, to upgrade your leg armor from Mk I to Mk IV you need to gather a certain amount of broken leg pieces Mk II, then Mk III etc.

From what I've read, in New Game Plus the tiers ("Marks") are higher the dropped tier level = old level +5 (so instead of Mk I i'd be getting MK VI). So if I'd start the NG + and the some equipment level that I have is just Mk I, will I be able to upgrade it? I know that I could just wait for that armor piece to drop again, but some of the armor sets are not available till late game and I might want to test them in NG + earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes.**

You will be able to upgrade these items from Mk.I to Mk.VI directly in NG+. You won't need any intermediate upgrade materials or nano cores.

This is my screenshot from NG++:

[image]

As you can see, it's possible to upgrade from Mk.I to Mk.XI directly using only Mk.XI parts and tech scraps.

Same for weapons:

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity - does this include weapons? Or do you need to get them first to Mk V using rare Nano Cores?

Comment: @Yasskier yes, it's the same for weapons, I've added 2nd screenshot